# MDX: SSRS Expression: Count Dimension members based on other Dimension

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssas, mdx, calculated-columns

I am pretty new to mdx expressions, and am currently trying to write a calculated member in SSRS (2012) that does pretty much the following:

**Dimension1 - CampaignNames
Dimension2 - Customers
Dimension3 - ContactDate**

now out of These three i want to see the Number(Count) of Customers that have been Contacted (for which there is a ContactDate, so basically where ContactDate is not Unknown or Null).
Logicaly maybe something like this

**Count(Customers) where ContactDate NonEmpty**
( I am not quite sure if i'm typing it correctly, this is just how i Thing it's done for now. i don't know if this would also exclude NULL Values.)
I want this to be done **Relative** to the CampaignName though, so when i put it on a table later, i could Group by Campaign Name and then Customers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to define this as an Analysis Services calculated measure, you could use something like this:

```
WITH member [Contacted Customers] as
     Exists([CustomersDim].[Customers].[Customers].Members,
            [ContactDateDim].[ContactDate].[ContactDate].Members,
            'contacts'
           ).Count
SELECT ...
```

As you did not state it, I was guessing that the dimension names are `CustomersDim` and `ContactDateDim`, and `Customers` and `ContactDate` are attribute hierarchy names, and that the name of the measure group connecting both dimensions is `contacts`.

Depending on query filters, you might want to change the second argument to `Exists` to take the filter into account.